# Symfony 3 : fulltext search

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

For my full text searchI used https://gist.github.com/ZeBigDuck/1234419/edaa13a851b1ea1e9926ec9c003ad762876ffe1d

It returns me an array with a score,:

```
array:1 [▼
0 => array:1 [▼
"score" => "2.181887149810791"
 ]
]
```

but I want it to return a collection of entity. How?

MatchAgainst class :

`

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;

class MatchAgainst extends FunctionNode
{    
public $columns = array();
public $needle;

public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
{
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
    $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

    do {
        $this->columns[] = $parser->StateFieldPathExpression();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
    } while (!$parser->getLexer()->isNextToken(Lexer::T_INPUT_PARAMETER));

    // Got an input parameter
    $this->needle = $parser->InputParameter();

    $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
}

public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
{
    $haystack = null;

    $first = true;
    foreach ($this->columns as $column) {
        $first ? $first = false : $haystack .= ', ';
        $haystack .= $column->dispatch($sqlWalker);
    }

    return "MATCH(" .
        $haystack .
        ") AGAINST (" .
        $this->needle->dispatch($sqlWalker) .
        " IN BOOLEAN MODE )";
}
}
```

`

in my repository :

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
        SELECT
        MATCH_AGAINST (d.title, :searchTerms) as score
        FROM AppBundle:Doc d
        WHERE MATCH_AGAINST (d.title, :searchTerms) > 1
        ORDER BY score desc
    ')
    ->setParameter('searchTerms', $q)
    ;
```

If i change my repository function to smething like

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
        SELECT d
        FROM AppBundle:Doc d
        MATCH_AGAINST (d.title, :searchTerms)        
    ')
    ->setParameter('searchTerms', $q)
    ;
```

I got

> Error: Expected end of string, got 'MATCH_AGAINST'

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do :

`->select("d")
        ->andWhere("MATCH_AGAINST (d.title, :searchTerms) > 1")
        ->setParameter('searchTerms', $q)`